# ngrx Reducer to change multiple states

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I can't find the way to create a reducer that changes multiple state, the API Rest returns nested data, which I normalize using normalizr library. Here is my code.

**Api returns data:**

```
[
  {id: 1, firstName: 'CRISTIAN', lastName: 'QUISPE', country: {id: 1, name: 'PERU'}},
  {id: 2, firstName: 'ISRRAEL', lastName: 'ALCAZAR', country: {id: 10, name: 'ESPAÑA'}}
];
```

**Schema normalizr:**

```
import {schema} from 'normalizr';

export const country = new schema.Entity('countries');
export const person = new schema.Entity('people', {
  country: country
});
```

**Normalized data:**
[image]

**State tree expected:**
[image]

Which should be the reducer that receives the data of the api rest and generates the previous state tree.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is effects: https://github.com/ngrx/effects You probably need a 3rd reducer that will use effects to dispatch actions to both people and country

Comment: @Eeks33 Thank you for your suggest, I've searched how to do with ngrx/effects but I didn't find any example, could you give me an example of the solution which you propose?.

Comment: added an answer with a code example, let me know if that helps

Comment: Ngrx/effect has nothing to do here. Yes effects are great for handling side effects (fetch data from an API for example). But in this case.. Plus I commented your answer as you'll end up with store inconsistency which is a bad idea (gonna break your app if you use a selector)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you've got your normalized data, you have 2 solutions :

1. Dispatch one action (for ex `updateCountriesAndPeople`) that will be handled by `countriesReducer` **and** `peopleReducer`
2. Dispatch 2 different actions :
   One for `countriesReducer`, let's call it `updateCountries`
   One for `peopleReducer`, let's call it `updatePeople`

The first is pretty straight forward :

```
const updateCountriesAndPeople = 'UPDATE_COUNTRIES_AND_PEOPLE';

function countriesReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case updateCountriesAndPeople: {
      // do what you want with payload.entities.countries
    }
  }
}

function peopleReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case updateCountriesAndPeople: {
      // do what you want with payload.entities.people
    }
  }
}
```

For the solution n°2, if you dispatch 2 actions, you'll end up in a state inconsistency between the 2 dispatch. And thus, if you want to avoid that you should use a library called [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions). It will allow you to dispatch multiple actions at once, and for example if you have some selectors to build your data, they'll be triggered only once.

Personally, sometimes I like to split my actions if I know I'll possibly want to re-use those small actions independently.

If you want something really simple, take the solution n°1 :).

Comment: @Maxine thank you for your answer. The solution n°2 work well, creating 2 reducer for every entity y doing a dispatch to each reducers as: 

store.dispatch({type: LOAD_PERSON, payload: normalizedData.entities.people})

store.dispatch({type: LOAD_COUNTRY, payload: normalizedData.entities.countries}

Comment: I just tried the solution number 1 and it works perfect, but that about in large projects for example if another api rest returns the following list of users: [{id: 1, userName: 'CQUISPE', person: {id: 1, firstName: 'CRISTIAN'}},
 {id: 2, userName: 'IALCAZAR', person: {id: 2, firstName: 'ISRRAEL'}},
] I would have to create another action like as:UPDATE_USER_AND_PEOPLE. My question is: I could create an action with a generic name like as: UPDATE_FROM_ENTITY and in all the reduce evaluate this action, this could affect the performance of the application assuming that I will have 100 entities.

Comment: No it's fine and it won't hurt performance. Reducers that doesn't handle the actions will just return the same state. And the big object or array is passed by reference so it doesn't matter, really :)